# Unable to write data in a csv file in a customized manner

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written a script to get data from a table and write them in a `csv` file. Required data are coming through and my script can write them in a csv file as well. However, the only problem I can't solve is to get all the data in separate columns. I wish to get `name` and `link` in separate columns but they are getting in a same column. How to fix that? Any help will be highly appreciated.

The script I'm trying with:

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content="""
<tr>
    <td align="center">1964</td>
    <td><span class="sortkey">Townes, Charles Hard</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Charles_Hard_Townes" class="mw-redirect" title="Charles Hard Townes">Charles Hard Townes</a></span></span>;<br>
    <span class="sortkey">Basov, Nikolay</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Nikolay_Basov" title="Nikolay Basov">Nikolay Basov</a></span></span>;<br>
    <span class="sortkey">Prokhorov, Alexander</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Alexander_Prokhorov" title="Alexander Prokhorov">Alexander Prokhorov</a></span></span></td>
    <td><span class="sortkey">Hodgkin, Dorothy</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Dorothy_Hodgkin" title="Dorothy Hodgkin">Dorothy Hodgkin</a></span></span></td>
    <td><span class="sortkey">Bloch, Konrad Emil</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Konrad_Emil_Bloch" title="Konrad Emil Bloch">Konrad Emil Bloch</a></span></span>;<br>
    <span class="sortkey">Lynen, Feodor Felix Konrad</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Feodor_Felix_Konrad_Lynen" class="mw-redirect" title="Feodor Felix Konrad Lynen">Feodor Felix Konrad Lynen</a></span></span></td>
    <td><span class="sortkey">Sartre, Jean-Paul</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Jean-Paul_Sartre" title="Jean-Paul Sartre">Jean-Paul Sartre</a></span></span><sup class="reference" id="ref_Note1D"><a href="#endnote_Note1D">[D]</a></sup></td>
    <td><span class="sortkey">King, Jr., Martin Luther</span><span class="vcard"><span class="fn"><a href="/wiki/Martin_Luther_King,_Jr." class="mw-redirect" title="Martin Luther King, Jr.">Martin Luther King, Jr.</a></span></span></td>
    <td align="center">—</td>
</tr>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for items in soup.select('tr'):
    item_name = [' '.join([item.text,item.get('href')]) for item in items.select(".fn a")]
    print(item_name)
    with open("tab_data.csv","a",newline="") as infile:
        writer = csv.writer(infile)
        writer.writerow(item_name)
```

Output I'm getting (name and link in same column):
[image]
Output I would like to have (name and link in separate column):
[image]

Btw, this is the follow up question of this thread: [Thread_Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48051766/unable-to-get-all-the-data-including-links-from-a-tr-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need text and url in different columns then you don't must to join them:

```
import itertools
...
for items in soup.select('tr'):
    list_of_tuples = [(item.text,item.get('href')) for item in items.select(".fn a")]
    item_name = list(itertools.chain(*list_of_tuples))
    print(item_name)
    with open("tab_data.csv","a",newline="") as infile:
        writer = csv.writer(infile)
        writer.writerow(item_name)
```

**EDIT** OP ask what means `*list_of_tuples`

First, we need to understand what means `itertools.chain( x, y )`. This is intended to 'chain' two lists (enumerables):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> x=[1,2,3]
>>> y=(4,5,6)
>>> itertools.chain( x, y )
<itertools.chain object at 0x7f5811df8690>
>>> list(itertools.chain( x, y ))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Now, we are ready to understand [unpacking arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists). Lets suppose we have our x and y parameters ( from example ) into a list: l = [x, y]. In this case, we can unpack this list with `*` operator:

```
>>> l=[x,y]
>>> list(itertools.chain( *l ))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

In your case, you have a lot of tuples you want to chain:

```
>>> t1=(1,2)
>>> t2=(3,4)
>>> t3=(4,5)
>>> list(itertools.chain( t1, t2, t3 ))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

But you have this tuples in a list you want to unpack:

```
>>> l=[t1, t2, t3]
>>> list(itertools.chain( *l ))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]
```

I hope this has sense for you.

Comment: Wow!! This is it. It did the job. One thing is slightly hard for me to understand which is `*list_of_tuples` the asterisk sign. Would you please care to provide a little explanation on this? Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Topto, explained on answer.

Comment: Thanks a trillion @danihp. Now, I get it.